# How to find errors in nested SELECT request in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a sum on field created using different columns of my table so I have make 2 nested SELECT.

My nested SELECT works good alone, but when I put it inside the other one I show errors and I can't find them out

I've tested my nested SELECT and it works.

```
DECLARE @Debut datetime ='2019-03-18'
DECLARE @Fin datetime = '2019-03-31'

SELECT  Secteur,
        Site_Theo,
        Techno,
        SUM(Trafic) as Trafic_Hebdo

        FROM (

SELECT  [TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].Trafic_voix as Trafic ,
        [INFO_CELL_N].SITE_THEO,
        [INFO_CELL_N].TECHNO,
        CONCAT('A' , right(SITE_THEO,5) , REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( right([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].Cellname, 1) , 'D' , 'A' ) , 'E' , 'B' ) , 'F' , 'C' ) ) as Secteur 

        FROM    [KIWI].[dbo].[TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO] INNER JOIN [KIWI].[dbo].[INFO_CELL_N]
        ON      [KIWI].[dbo].[TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].Cellname = [KIWI].[dbo].[INFO_CELL_N].CELLNAME


        WHERE   (   right([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].cellname,1)='A' OR
                    right([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].cellname,1)='B' OR
                    right([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].cellname,1)='C' OR 
                    right([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].cellname,1)='D' OR 
                    right([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].cellname,1)='E' OR 
                    right([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].cellname,1)='F'   )

                AND ( [TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].TSTAMP BETWEEN @Debut AND @Fin )

                )
GROUP BY Secteur, Site_Teho, Techno
```

Error Message:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'GROUP'.

I would like to understand why I have errors.
To me the code looks good

Comment: What are the errors, please?

Comment: What is the error msg

Comment: Subqueries must be aliased to a name, even if it's just `_`. `SELECT ... FROM ( ... )` isn't allowed; `SELECT ... FROM ( ... ) _` is. For greater clarity, consider a CTE: `;WITH subquery AS (...) SELECT * FROM subquery`.

Comment: Yes sorry i forgot to put it :
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 34
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a ALIAS to you sub query as -

```
SELECT ....
FROM (
    SELECT...
)A -- A is the alias
GROUP BY Secteur, Site_Teho, Techno
```

Secondly, you can write your WHERE as below-

```
     WHERE RIGHT([TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].cellname, 1) IN ( 'A','B','C','D','E','F')
     AND [TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].TSTAMP BETWEEN @Debut AND @Fin
```

Answer (score 0):

A derived table must have a name - provide it immediately after the closing parenthesis and before "group by ".

```
select Secteur,
...
from ( SELECT  [TRAFIC_VOIX_HEBDO].Trafic_voix as Trafic ,
... 
) as usefulnamehere
group by Secteur, Site_Teho, Techno
order by ...;
```